# Probability that Three Numbers Drawn Represent Sides of a Triangle

Tags: probability, triangles, gre-exam

Suppose three numbers are randomly chosen from the following list:
\begin{equation}
4,5,7,8,11
\end{equation}
What is the probability that the numbers drawn represent sides of a triangle?

---

I posted my attempted solution below. Please let me know if it looks like a good strategy. It did take quite a while to figure out every possible combination of numbers which work, so if you think of a quicker approach please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My attempted solution**:

Use the *triangle inequality* theorem: For any three side lengths $a,b,c$, these lengths represent sides of a triangle if $x+y \ge z$ holds for every possible $x,y,z \in \{a,b,c\}$.

Therefore, the following triples representing possible triangle side lengths are:

4,5,7

4,5,8

4,7,8

4,8,11

5,7,8

5,7,11

5,8,11

7,8,11

And the number of possibilities (where order does not matter) is:
\begin{equation}
_5C_3=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=\frac{120}{12}=10
\end{equation}
Thus the desired probability is $\frac{8}{10}=\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: It’s correct, but you could make it a little simpler by just pointing out that the only sets that *don’t* make a triangle are $\{4,5,11\}$ and $\{4,7,11\}$; since there are $\binom53=10$ sets, there must be $10-2=8$ sets that *do* make triangles.

Comment: I included $4,7,11$ as one of my possible triangles (of course it's perfectly flat; I don't know if this is what the test intended but it satisfies the triangle inequality). I think $4,5,11$ is the only combination that doesn't work, isn't it?

Comment: If they’re looking for non-degenerate triangles, you want to exclude both; if they allow degenerate triangles, then yes, $\{4,5,11\}$ is the only bad set.

Comment: Edit: Whoops, I had missed one of the possible triangles! Thanks!

Comment: That’s what you get: your list of $8$ doesn’t include the degenerate one. Okay now?

Comment: Great! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Mathemanic: This does assume that the numbers chosen are distinct, which is only mildly suggested by the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

{4,5,11} and {4,7,11} can work too if you change the units of the "offending" side to force it to work so it depends on what you allow and what you disallow and since you didn't specify, I am saying 100% is possible cuz I can change the units for the 11 side to be something that completes the triangle.